# Angular: How to detect toggle status in ng-bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, toggle, ng-bootstrap

I am working with [this dropdowns](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples).

How can I detect in the template or ts file the status of the dropdown modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the built-in function isOpen() to get a boolean value of whether a particular dropdown is opened or closed

the detail is given in the [API, methods section](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api#NgbDropdown)

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-basic',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdDropdownBasic {
    @ViewChild(NgbDropdown)
  private dropdown: NgbDropdown;

  checkDropDown() {
    return this.dropdown.isOpen();
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not know of the api section till now... *face palm.*

Comment: We've all been there... Happy coding 

Comment: Hey, kindly check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491156/angular-how-to-detect-toggle-status-in-ng-bootstrap-dropdown-where-there-are-se). Thanks