# Angular: How to detect toggle status in ng-bootstrap dropdown where there are several dropdowns

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, toggle, ng-bootstrap

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473532/angular-how-to-detect-toggle-status-in-ng-bootstrap-dropdown/56475085?noredirect=1#comment99554807_56475085) and it was well answered.

But I have another question: How to detect toggle status in ng-bootstrap dropdown where there are several dropdowns?

When [I try doing it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gyv9j?file=app/dropdown-config.ts) returns the status of the firstdropdown only. I cannot use a unique id as they don't contain the 'isopen()' method.

How can I detect toggle status in ng-bootstrap dropdown where there are several dropdowns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like this:

I get all the dropdowns with `ViewChildren`

```
@ViewChildren(NgbDropdown)
dropdowns: QueryList<NgbDropdown>;
dropdown: NgbDropdown;
```

Then I would change `checkDropDown` method in this way:

```
checkDropDown(dropdown: any) {
  // Check which dropdown was clicked
  this.dropdown = this.dropdowns.find(x => (x as any)._elementRef.nativeElement == dropdown)
  // Check if the clicked dropdown is open
  console.log(this.dropdown.isOpen())
}
```

You should change your html file as well, by using template ref:

```
<div #drop1 ngbDropdown>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle (click)="checkDropDown(drop1)">Toggle-1</button>

...

<div #drop2 ngbDropdown>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle (click)="checkDropDown(drop2)">Toggle-2</button>
```

I drop here a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gyv9j-kh2rns?file=app/dropdown-config.ts) too.

P.S. Your buttons have the same ids, remove them: `dropdownConfig`

Comment: why not use (openChange)???? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api

Comment: Because as a beginner you one cannot really understand the docs without an example... [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56493068/9953550) just helped understand the docs. @Eliseo

Comment: Yeah it’s better using openChange than click, but I’m not sure your checkDropDown method is the best practice. Think if you have the reference to one dropdown in your ts (with a ViewChild for example). With my solution you can check its status anytime, instead your solution is bounded with the openChange event. I’ll update the stackblitz with a use case.

Comment: @Eliseo take a look [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gyv9j-kh2rns?file=app/dropdown-config.ts). That's what I was talking about.

Comment: FedericoGalfione, what you are saying is actually true and a very interesting observation, @Eliseo should include a link to you answer in the accepted answer for anyone looking for youe specific solution to easily find it in the future.

Comment: @FedericoGalfione, Just use #drop1="ngbDropDown" and pass as argument of the function. I updated the stackblitz to understand

Answer (score 11):

why not use (openChange)???? see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gyv9j-7p7cye?file=app%2Fdropdown-config.html)

```
<div #drop1 ngbDropdown (openChange)="checkDropDown($event,1)">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle >Toggle-1</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownConfig">
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: If we can refered to the dropdown, we write

```
<div #drop1="ngbDropdown" 
      ngbDropdown (openChange)="checkDropDown($event,drop1)">
....
</div>
checkDropDown(open:boolean,dropdown: NgbDropdown) {
    console.log(open,dropdown.placement)

}
```

**UPDATE**, the official docs of ngbDropdown is [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api). Can be difficult undestand the API, so, try to explain sucintaly

Inputs are properties that we can add in .html as

```
<div ngbDropdown [propertie]="variable"..>
//or
<div ngbDropdown propertie="valor" ...>
//if is a string, don't forget use simple quotes e.g.
<div ngbDropdown autoClose="'outside'" ...>
```

Outputs son "events", if return a value we get the response using $event, e.g.

```
<div ngbDropdown (openChange)="myFunction($event)" ...>
//If we can send more arguments, simply
<div ngbDropdown (openChange)="myFunction($event,"some more")" ...>
```

And Methods are method that we can use in the .ts is we has a ViewChild or ViewChildren

```
<div #myngbDropdown ngbDropdown [propertie]="variable"..>

@ViewChild('myngbDropDown') mydrop:nhbDropDown;

ngOnAtferView()
{
    console.log(this.mydrop.isOpen())
}
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to know more here is [a link to the docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api) for ‘open change’... @Eliso kindly include the link to the docs to your answer. It goes a really long way in making people understand the code better.

Comment: Sorry @YulePale, you're ok. I updated my answer with a briefly explain to understand a few the docs, I hope this can help